Is the law of entropy just probabilistic and not valid in small system where entropy can decrease?
My question is that is the law of entropy which states that the entropy in a system always increases valid at all
The law is only probabilistic in small systems like of 100 particles this law can be violated, my argument is that no matter how big the system is, if given enough time the law of entropy can still be violated
Please forgive if my framing is bad

I think this is the same as Can the second law of thermodynamics be violated in a small enough system if tried repeatedly enough? though that was never answered.

Also Is a spontaneous decrease in entropy impossible or just extremely unlikely?

@JohnRennie The second question you cited has been answered (ten answers!), so I am marking this question as a duplicate of that question.

This question is similar to: Is a spontaneous decrease in entropy *impossible* or just extremely unlikely?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
